# HELP, failed to import database to phpmysql

Tags: apache2, mysql, backup, debian, phpmyadmin

HELP ME MASTER -_-
I'm just learning to install linux again, my fault, forgot to backup the database via phpmyadmin, only backup copy folder in var/www/html

from debian version 8..., I tried to change ubuntu version 20..

[enter image description here][1]

I have installed phpmyadmin, but when importing the file, it fails

and this file has not been compressed

[enter image description here][1]

I've tried to compress .sql.zip, .zip., but still can't, HELP ME -_-

Comment: so you still have access to your old database? can you connect to it? what is the error you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.